# Building a Web Browser

Tags: firefox, browser, chromium

As much as I'd love to ask it, this isn't one of those "How to make a web browser questions."

I am currently downloading Chromium. And Wow. It's **huge**. How can a browser be so massive? Especially when you compare it to the actual finished product that you download, which is only about 200MB.

Anyway. My question is, where can I obtain the source of Mozilla's browser? I have found a link from a Google search, but the page is telling me I do not have permission to view the requested page. Is there another resource I can obtain this download from online?

Comment: Like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives)?

Comment: Thanks @Passerby this link seems to be working just fine. Would you have any idea of how big the file download size is?

Comment: No, I never compile a browser myself.

Comment: Ok no worries. Thanks for your help. I'd be willing to accept your answer if you post it as an answer. If you want.

Comment: There are several reasons the source download for a browser is huge.  It includes all the debugging code that's compiled out in the shipping version.  It includes code for multiple operating systems and hardware architectures.  It often includes some amount of developer documentation.  It includes the regression tests developers need to run (including whatever image/audio/video files are needed to test the relevant HTML tags).  Just looking at my mozilla checkout, there are 40+MB of tests for the JS engine and another 65+MB of tests for the layout engine...

Comment: That's very interesting, @BorisZbarsky. Thanks for the info. I have broadband but it's no better than dialup atm. I wish there was a way to choose which parts you could download.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, extending from comment:

According to [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Source_Code/Downloading_Source_Archives), you can obtain Firefox source code from their [FTP](ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/), using the version in path:

```
ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/PROJECT/releases/RELEASE/source/
```

where the names in CAPITAL LETTERS mean the following:

- PROJECT - The project name, such as *firefox* or *thunderbird*.
- RELEASE - The release, such as *1.5.0.3* or *bonecho*.

For example, the source code for Firefox release 2.0.0.4 can be found at the following URL:

```
ftp://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/2.0.0.4/source/
```